# `Bad Value` when connecting to an external API in google app script

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, convertapi

Trying to fetch data from the [ConvertAPI's web to jpg](https://www.convertapi.com/web-to-jpg) but the program throws an error for a `Bad Value`. Here's my code :

```
const url = 'https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/web/to/png?Secret=...'
  const prams = [
    {
      "Name": "Url",
      "Value": "..."
    }
  ];

  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url, prams));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- From [your provided document](https://www.convertapi.com/web-to-jpg), you want to convert the following HTTP request to Google Apps Script.

  ```
    POST https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/web/to/jpg?Secret=<YOUR SECRET HERE>
    Content-Type: application/json

    {
        "Parameters": [
            {
                "Name": "Url",
                "Value": ""
            },
            {
                "Name": "StoreFile",
                "Value": true
            }
        ]
    }
  ```

Unfortunately, your `prams` cannot be directly used for UrlFetchApp. And, `UrlFetchApp.getRequest` doesn't request. And also, your `prams` is different from the sample of the document you provided.

When these points are reflected in Google Apps Script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const url = 'https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/web/to/jpg?Secret=<YOUR SECRET HERE>';
  const prams = {
    "Parameters": [
      {
        "Name": "Url",
        "Value": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": "StoreFile",
        "Value": true
      }
    ]
  };
  const options = {
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify(prams),
  };
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  console.log(res.getContentText());
}
```

- If an error occurs, please confirm your `Secret` and the values of `prams` again.

#### Note:

- In the document, there is a sample curl command of `curl -F "Url=" -F "StoreFile=true" https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/web/to/jpg?Secret=<YOUR SECRET HERE>`. When this is converted to Google Apps Script, it becomes as follows.

  ```
    const url = "https://v2.convertapi.com/convert/web/to/jpg?Secret=<YOUR SECRET HERE>";
    const options = { payload: { "StoreFile": "true", "Url": "" } };
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    console.log(res.getContentText());
  ```
- Please test the above 2 patterns.

#### References:

- [WEB to JPG API](https://www.convertapi.com/web-to-jpg#snippet=json)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: This just gave me an http error

Comment: @Vayun Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current situation from only `This just gave me an http error`. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide detailed information about it? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Vayun please read the body of the response and let us know what error do you get. Tanaike posted a working solution for you.